# Что это за тип в C#?

Tags: c#

Что это за тип. Коллекция?

```
new { param1 = "data1", param2 = "data2" };
```

Comment: [Анонимные типы](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/anonymous-types).

Comment: Нет, не коллекция, анонимный объект с двумя свойствами, класс.